# Redirect to a custom page in hook_init()

Tags: hooks

I need to redirect users to a custom page using `hook_init()`.

I have tried `drupal_goto()`, but it is not working fine. By using drupal_goto(), it is looping and it is not giving the correct result.

So, for that, I have checked a condition using `drupal_get_destination()`. But, it is not working correctly.

Here is the code:

```
$destination = drupal_get_destination();

foreach($compatible_arr as $key => $val) {
if(isset($browser_arr[$key])) {
    if(version_compare($browser_arr[$key], $val, '<')) {
        //print strpos($destination['destination'], 'browser-limitations');
        if(strpos($destination['destination'], 'browser-limitations') == '') {
            drupal_goto($base_url.'/browser-limitations/', array('query' => array('version' => $val)));
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this condition in order to check the browser version using the [Mobile Detect](https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_detect) module. But, I am not getting the correct result. Is it safe to use drupal_goto() in hook_init()? Or else, is there any function to use it?

Comment: hook_init doesn't work in cached pages, thats why you get the improper redirection. Use hook_boot() once with S_SERVER redirect. That will work.

Comment: Strange! I came across similar situation where I wasn't able to redirect the user inside `hook_init` using `drupal_goto`. I ended up using the PHP function `header('Location: '. <path_var>);` and it worked. This is again strange, since `drupal_goto` makes a call to the `header` function in its implementation. I wasn't able to search for the cause that time, will try to search it now.

Comment: @Gladiator: It didn't work in hook_boot().

Comment: @Kiran Tej: Did you use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ? But remember one thing, the Drupal API will not be recognized in hook_boot(), hence you might need PHP way of doing some stuffs.

Comment: `drupal_get_destination()` is used for redirection. Meaning, if you get a result, you already are in a redirection process. What exactly are you trying to achieve with that first line ?

Comment: Also, `drupal_goto()` doesn't need a `/` in the front, and in your case you would probably end up with 2 :-) `//browser-limitations/...`. `drupal_goto()` already knows about the base path, so you don't need to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you define the redirect in hook_init, then it would work for non cached pages. But in case of Cached pages it would not work.

So it is recommended to use hook_boot instead of hook_init.

hook_boot would help you in redirecting for cached pages as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you just need `header()` (a PHP function) instead of `drupal_goto()`.

```
$destination = drupal_get_destination();

foreach ($compatible_arr as $key => $val) {
  if (isset($browser_arr[$key])) {
    if (version_compare($browser_arr[$key], $val, '<')) {
      //print strpos($destination['destination'], 'browser-limitations');
      if (strpos($destination['destination'], 'browser-limitations') == '') {
        $url = $base_url . '/browser-limitations?version=' . $val;
        header('Location: ' . $url);
        exit;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It is better you put your code in [hook_preprocess_page()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) instead of using `hook_init()`.

Comment: Yes, `hook_preprocess_page()` is a better idea, also because Drupal 8 doesn't use `hook_init()` anymore.

Comment: I disagree. using `hook_preprocess_page()` would make you hook into the theme process. That's awfully late for a redirection, and a waste of performance. And using `header()` doesn't seem like a solution either, as `drupal_goto()`is basically just a wrapper for it (with some minor extra functionality).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from reading you code again, I think I understand what you are trying to achieve.

First, you want to get the current path ("destination"). This is not the way to do that:

```
$destination = drupal_get_destination();
```

`drupal_get_destination()` is used when redirecting a user *after* some event (like a form submission). In your case, this will return nothing (or at least not what you expect). Which is why your code triggers an infinite loop: the checking if `$destination` contains `browser-limitations`will always fail, as `$destination` is treated as an empty string (or contains some other path than the current one).

You must use:

```
$destination = current_path();
```

This will give you the current internal path, the path that is currently being loaded.

Then, you probably want to check if you're on the `browser-limitations`page BEFORE looping. Saves you a few ms. And finally, `drupal_goto()` expects an internal path, so you can simplify your final call (no `/` in front or after, don't worry about `base_path()`).

```
if (!preg_match('/browser-limitations/', $destination)) {
  foreach($compatible_arr as $key => $val) {
    if(isset($browser_arr[$key])) {
      if(version_compare($browser_arr[$key], $val, '<')) {
        drupal_goto('browser-limitations', array('query' => array('version' => $val)));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Try that.